# Is it OK to Think of Electric Charge as Mass?

Tags: electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, mass, charge, coulombs-law

Since both are physical properties, is it ok to think of them as if they are the same thing, just in different contexts? Mass affects how much an object experiences gravity in a gravitational field, and charge affects how much an object experiences an electrical field. (What exactly does a particle experience in an electrical field?)

If it is ok to think of them as the same thing, then why could there be a positive and negative charge, but it is impossible for there to exist a negative mass?

Comment: All questions of the form "Is it okay to do X?" have the same answer:   It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

A proton has positive charge and positive mass. A proton is attracted by an electron and falls to earth.

An electron has a negative charge and positive mass. An electron is repelled by an electron and falls to earth.

We know of many things that have negative charge, but nothing that has negative mass.

Electric charge creates a much stronger force than gravity. A single electron and strongly repel another electron. It takes a large mass, such as the entire Earth, to noticeably affect an electron.
So it is easy to find ways that they are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Electric charge and mass are not the same thing, although there is a pair of equations in which they look similar, namely Coulomb's Law and Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation:
\begin{align}
\vec F_E &= \frac{kq_1q_2}{\lVert\vec r\rVert^2}\hat r\\
\vec F_g &= -\frac{GM_1M_2}{\lVert\vec r\rVert^2}\hat r
\end{align}

Here, $q$ are the electric charges, $M$ are the gravitational masses (or gravitational charges), $\vec r$ is the displacement between the objects, and $k$ and $G$ are some constants to make the equations dimensionally correct.
There are two important distinctions between these equations. The first is obvious: there is a negative sign in the equation for gravitational force, meaning that the gravitational and electric forces act in opposite directions for the same pair of "charges." The second is less obvious: the main place where we care about forces is Newton's Second Law
$$\vec F_{\text{net}} = m\vec a$$
where $m$ is the inertial mass. As it turns out, it happens to be the case that $m=M$, all objects have the same inertial and gravitational masses. This means that an set of objects with given masses and a given set of initial conditions will always follow the same trajectories when subjected only to the gravitational force. However, the same cannot be said for a set of objects with given electric charges subjected only to the electric force, because their trajectories also depend on their (inertial) masses.

---

All of the discussion above assumes that we are working within the classical regime where electricity and gravity do look similar in accordance with the laws of Coulomb and Newton. However, at different scales, the phenomena of electricity and gravity do not always look so similar. For example, general relativity treats gravity as spacetime curvature, whereas there is not something analogous for electricity.